# /System/Library/Kernels/kernel is Unsigned on MacOs Monterey

Tags: macos, security, malware

process "kernel_task (pid: 0)" /System/Library/Kernels/kernel appears to be unsigned in  Objective See TaskExplorer, though it is not flagged by VirusTotal: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/af6075a6d10e2abfba1142f44518962b7e8e367a8f7c31bc981d069a4c13ae8a/detection.

This looks strange to me.
I supposed this file should be signed by "Apple Root CA".

It is normal ?

Comment: I've found this https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7505783 but can't really trust it

Comment: also found that https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/9z9clw/little_snitch_macos_kernel_not_signed/